# Python - Console App - обработка команд из консоли

Tags: python, консоль

написал модуль, находится в папке под названием "`FooBar`", вызываю из консоли - `> python FooBar`.. все работает.. только как вот схватывать, обрабатывать команды написанные прямо в консоли(видел это у многих библиотек), например -

```
> python FooBar [command]
> python FooBar Run #пример
```

Comment: Аргументы командной строки, разве нет? `sys.argv`. Также рекомендую стандартный модуль `argparser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За консольные команды отвечает модуль из стандартной библиотеки `sys`.
Переменные которые вы передаете в командной строке записываются в `sys.argv`.
`sys.argv[0]` - это сам скрипт
`sys.argv[1]` - флаг который идет первым после модуля и т.п.
Пример(test.py):

```
import sys

def test1():
    print('sys.argv1')


def test2():
    print('sys.argv2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'test1':
        test()
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'test2':
        test2()
```

`>python test test1`
`>'sys.argv1'`

Comment: т.е. таким способом можно сделать анализ веденных команд типо имя_программы -help выйдет к примеру справка, или типо имя_программы -o -filename test.txt Правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Nelson, да, правильно. Но вручную не очень удобно разбирать. Я в последнее время делаю через click (ссылка в соседнем ответе).

Answer (score 4):

Простой пример, демонстрирующий как можно просмотреть параметры переданные скрипту при запуске:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

В Python есть множество библиотек, повышающих удобство работы с параметрами командной строки: [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html), [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) (и его замена [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)), [docopt](http://docopt.org/), [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/).

Вот тут есть хороший сравнительный обзор этих библиотек: [Comparing Python Command-Line Parsing Libraries - Argparse, Docopt, and Click](https://realpython.com/blog/python/comparing-python-command-line-parsing-libraries-argparse-docopt-click/)

Лично для себя, я выбрал `docopt`.